# Change the effectivedate from a line to auto nxt month

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a Quote form which is opened in an iframe and I have trouble changing the `effectiveDate`.

Here is the line:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="effectiveDate" value="02/02/2014"/>
```

I need to update the effective date `"02/02/2014"` to the first day of the next month. How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$d="02/02/2014";
$firstdaynextmonth=date("Y-m-01",strtotime("$d +1 month"));
```

Comment: sorry need a bit of explanation, I m a bit noob on this

Comment: you'll need to explain more about what you need to do exactly and what you mean by "change." Is it a manual change or a change made by a php script? Where is the quote, on a website you manage?

Comment: it s form to fill in for customer and then they get real time quote but in an iframe

Comment: You seed the Div underneath the quote form in the code ? Should be auto

Comment: You don t seem to be there anymore so I removed the link, feel free to ask if you are back or somebody help who s ok to help

Comment: Ok I m taking over that website and I don t know from where came that date 2/2/2014, The calculation should be based on today's date and default to the first of the next month after today's date.